# Как с помощью JS изменить масштаб браузера?

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка, google-chrome

Как с помощью JS изменить масштаб браузера? Например, пользователь установил 110% масштаб. При переходе на мою html страничку хотелось бы установить масштаб на 100%
[image: Изменение масштаба браузера]

Comment: посмотрите [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21093570/force-page-zoom-at-100-with-js)

Comment: у JS нет доступа к этой настройке, соответственно и установить ее невозможно.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то простое решение выглядит так:

```
document.body.style.zoom = 1.1;
```

Comment: К сожалению, такое решение справедливо для ограниченного числа браузеров.
В сафари будет лететь верстка, в фф свойство не поддерживается

Comment: zoom элемента не очень связан с зумом самой страницы

Answer (score 1):

Кроссбраузерно - никак. Это базовая потребность пользователя - иметь возможность изменять масштаб, она входит в список требований к доступности ПО. Вы должны адаптировать свое приложение к масштабу, который установил пользователь и тестировать поведение при разных настройках масштаба. Из html вы можете только установить рекомендуемое значение зума с помощью мета-тега
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`